# Comparing a datetimepicker with a string

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i'm pretty new into coding and visual basic. Today I was assigned to complete a program that i'm having some trouble with. I need to develop an app that allows the user to enter the appointment and the time it needs to be competed, however i need to implement an error check to make sure no two times are the same, this is where i'm running into problems. I'm unsure how i can compare a `datetimepicker.value` to the `listbox` text. I'm getting the Conversion from `string` "" to type `Date` is not valid error. Any help is much appreciated!

```
Public Class Form1

    Function TimeTaken() As Boolean
        Dim app As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim timeofapp As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortTimeString


        If CDate(ListBox2.Text) = CDate(DateTimePicker1.Value) Then
            MsgBox("Two appointments are scheduled within the same time frame.",              MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            TimeTaken = True
        Else
            TimeTaken = False
            ListBox1.Items.Add(app)
            ListBox2.Items.Add(timeofapp)
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If

    End Function


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TimeTaken()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

"I'm unsure how i can compare a datetimepicker.value to the listbox text"

You need to iterate over all the values stored in the ListBox.Items() property:

```
Function TimeTaken() As Boolean
    Dim AlreadyTaken As Boolean = False ' assume not taken until proven otherwise below

    Dim app As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim timeofapp As String = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortTimeString

    For Each time As String In ListBox2.Items
        If time = timeofapp Then
            MsgBox("Two appointments are scheduled within the same time frame.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            AlreadyTaken = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not AlreadyTaken Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(app)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(timeofapp)
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    End If

    Return AlreadyTaken
End Function
```

Comment: Awesome.  If that code solved your problem, feel free to click the checkmark to change that answer to the "accepted" one.